# How do you add multiple nodes to scene and move all of them at once. swift. sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new to swift and spriteKit. I am creating a side scrolling game. I want it to add multiple nodes(called Impenitrible) from the right side of the screen at any height and move left. My function for creating the "Impenitrible" node is :

```
func spawnImpenitrible(){
   Impenitrible.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Impenitrible.size)
           let actionDone =  SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var MinValue = sand.size.height
    var MaxValue = self.size.height - Impenitrible.size.height / 2
    var spawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    Impenitrible.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width - 60 , y: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(spawnPoint)))

    Impenitrible.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.impenitrible
    Impenitrible.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.sub
    Impenitrible.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Impenitrible.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.addChild(Impenitrible)


}
```

I call this function with:

```
var impenitribleTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnImpenitrible"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I move it by subtracting a number from the x position in the "Update" function.

It works fine adding Impenitrible once. but once it calls the function again the app crashes with error of :
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent
where did i go wrong? Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Your `spawnInpenitrible` doesn't actually *spawn* a node - it just uses the same node you already created somewhere else - you need to call the initialiser for `Impenitrible` and save that reference - probably in an array rather than a single variable as you have now

Comment: Don't use NSTimer in SpriteKit - the SpriteKit game engine is unaware of any NSTimers and can't control them (e.g. when you wish to pause the game, NSTimers continue to run). Look into SKActions.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that your line of code: `let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()` is effectively useless because you never call `runAction` to use it.

The error message sums it up quite nicely. "Attempted to add a SKNode which already has a parent". You never actually call `removeFromParent()`.

Adding `Impenitrible` once works fine as you found out, because at the start, `Impenitrible` has no parent. Subsequent calls will have a conflict because `Impenitrible` already has the parent that was added via the first call.

A quick and dirty fix is to do a `runAction(SKAction.removeFromParent())` before the next call of `spawnImpenitrible`, somewhere, referencing `Imprenitrible`.